# How to remove empty elements from txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove the empty elements from list of strings in copy of txt file. 
Previously I made a split by elements and led the strings a to lower case.
The concern point is to remove the empty elements from the list, the code is not gonna work. I tried to write a function, the code is below:

```
with open('text_file.txt','r') as rf:
    with open('text_file_copy.txt','w') as wf:
        for line in rf:
            line=line.lower() # lower case
            line=re.split(r'\s*', line) *# split elements by spaces*
            line=str(line)
            wf.write(line) *# writing to a file copy*
            line=wf.write(line)
            def empty_delete(line):
                new_line = []
                for word in line:
                    if word != '':
                        new_line.append(word)
                        return new_line
                    line=str(new_line)
                    wf.write(new_line) *# writing new list to a copy*
```

The text still has some empty elements: 
['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs,', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process.', '']['in', 'comparison', 'to', 'dogs,', 'cats', 'have', 'not', 'undergone', 'major', 'changes', 'during', 'the', 'domestication', 'process.', '']

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. In particular we need to know the exact structure of your text file, preferably a sample text file and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you remove empty and blank lines from an iterable (e.g. an open file):

```
for line in ...:
   if not line or line.isspace():
     continue # Ignore this line
   # Do something usefule with the line.
```